# SparkR dataframe with R lists as elements

Tags: r, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, sparkr

I have an R data.frame where one of the columns contains integer **lists** -- i.e., each of its elements embeds a whole list of integers. I'd like to convert this data.frame to a SparkR DataFrame, though SparkR is returning an error.

Here's how to create an example R data.frame that gives the issue:

```
indices <- 1:4
myDf <- data.frame(indices)
myDf$data <- list(rep(0, 20))
```

Looking at `myDf` gives the following (as I'd expect):

```
> str(myDf) 
'data.frame':   4 obs. of  2 variables:  
 $ indices: int  1 2 3 4  
 $ data   :List of 4
   ..$ : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
   ..$ : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
   ..$ : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
   ..$ : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

> head(myDf)   
  indices                                                       data 
1       1 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 
2       2 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 
3       3 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 
4       4 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

And creating a SparkR DataFrame from it actually does execute without error:

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc=paste0(Sys.getenv("SPARK_HOME"),"/R/lib"))
sparkR.session(master = "local[*]")

mySparkDf <- as.DataFrame(myDf)
```

However, subsequent operations on `mySparkDf` don't seem to work:

```
> collect(mySparkDf)
17/07/13 17:23:00 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.Double is not a valid external type for schema of array<double>
if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt) null 
else validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, indices), IntegerType) AS indices#0
... long stack trace ...
```

According to the Spark [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types), lists should in fact be allowed? Even looking at the schema for the Spark DataFrame shows that the list is (successfully) stored as an ArrayType:

```
> schema(mySparkDf)
StructType
|-name = "indices", type = "IntegerType", nullable = TRUE
|-name = "data", type = "ArrayType(DoubleType,true)", nullable = TRUE
```

Using Spark 2.2.0, R 3.4.0, Java 1.8.0_131.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

i have tried this code after execution i got error while converting to sparkdataframe.ie

```
Error in structField.character(names[[i]], types[[i]], TRUE) : 
  Field type must be a string.
```

i think myDf cant be converted to sparkdataframe.
you can convert mySparkDf <- as.DataFrame(myDf$data) like this.
but you wont get the desired output.

Comment: Thanks. Think this is a matter of sending a feature request to Spark?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to normalize your data in R first. I am getting the same error as @midhunxavier.  The array type double is trouble in spark r. Have you considered using the purr package in R to normalize your data first? Here is a link that may be helpful: https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls13_list-columns.html

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes actually right now my workaround is to move all the list elements to their own columns of the data.frame... However since my data is semi-structured, it'd be much more convenient to maintain the embedded lists... When you say, "the array type double is trouble in spark r"... is it a bug?

Comment: I don't think `array` types are supported in SparkR at the moment...be it an array composed of doubles or strings or otherwise...that's why I said they cause a lot of trouble. However, I think there may be a work around to this if you convert your dataframe to JSON and then read that into SparkR 2.2.0+ and use the `as.json.array` option. Take a peek at https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/R/pkg/R/functions.R  around line 2174. The from json command might be able to help here, but I'm not 100% sure. I don't want to send you down a path to nowhere, but maybe it could help...